# Image won't Render in Site

Tags: html, css, ruby, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am building a site in Bridgetown using Bootstrap 5 and I am trying to add an image but it won't render in the site. This is what it looks like[image]

### Code

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="/output/images/logo-topnav.png" alt=" Name" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
    </a>

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <button
      type="button"
      class="navbar-toggler"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navmenu"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
    </button>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  </div>
 
</nav>
```

Comment: Where's the picture located and also what's it's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you used the wrong image link. Check the image address or just copy it from VSC if you use that.